# How to zoom specific area of imageview based on click in android

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am trying to figure out how to zoom in on a full screen image based on user click on the image. I want to zoom only that much area where user clicked.I have divided the full screen image into 20 (5*4 )grids and i am detecting the click on grids. On click of these grid i want to full screen the respective click grid image.
 How can i fetch that x and y coordinate and dynamically apply zoom in? please help me to figure this out.

Comment: pinch zoom or double tap zoom in imageview?

Comment: updated the question for the reference. I want to zoom in the image on click and then display each grid image as full screen